# How can I get different spacing between lines and between "paragraphs"?

Tags: html, css, text

I have a box in which text is presented in spans. I used line-height to change the spacing within a section, but need to have a different distance between sections.

See orange box on this page:
https://theslowroad.org/category/destinations/asia/laos/#

I tried using margins and padding but it doesn't seem to have an effect.

```
        '<span class="boxhead">' . 'Major stops:' . '</span>' . '<span class="boxtext">' . $where . '</span>' . '<br>' .
        '<span class="boxhead">' . 'Memorable moment:' . '</span>' . '<span class="boxtext">' . $moment . '</span>' . '<br>' .
        '<span class="boxhead">' . 'Did you know?' . '</span>' . '<span class="boxtext">' . $fact . '</span>';
    ?>
```

CSS:

```
.boxhead {
    margin-right: 18px; 
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding-bottom: 19px;
}

.boxtext {
padding-bottom: 19px;
}

.infobox {
    line-height: 1.2em;
    clear: both;
    background-color: #bf593a;
    color: white;
    padding: 5%;
    border-radius: 10px ;
    margin-left:6%;
    margin-right: 6%;
    margin-top: 8%;
    margin-bottom: 10%;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: `span`'s are inline elements, try with `p` tags for line separated paragraphs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way is to change your .boxtext selector to:

```css
.boxtext {
  padding-bottom: 19px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

But I suggest grouping all the span.boxhead span.boxtext classes with a `<div class="boxgroup">`

```php
'<div class="boxgroup"><span class="boxhead">Major stops:</span> <span class="boxtext">' . $where . '</span></div>' .
'<div class="boxgroup"><span class="boxhead">Memorable moment:</span> <span class="boxtext">' . $moment . '</span></div>' .
'<div class="boxgroup"><span class="boxhead">Did you know?</span> <span class="boxtext">' . $fact . '</span></div>';
```

(also took some liberty removing superfluous string concats, hope you don't mind.)

and changing the .boxtext selector to:

```css
.boxgroup {
  padding-bottom: 19px;
}
```

Comment: Perfect--thanks! (I'm so new to this. I really appreciate help.)